# Having trouble turning my Javascript Object into a parameter string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an object with the following data structure below. I am trying to turn this object into a parameter string by doing the following below.

When my code snippet is run in the debugger I don't see an error in the console but it submits the form prematurely for some reason and in the URL I can see my params being posted and stops the rest of my script. The Object,keys does not look right and is producing the following int he debugger.

```
keys
(273) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", * "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "9 3", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", CJ
•   [0  99]
•   [100    199]
•   [200    272]
length: 273
•       proto   : Array(0)
```

What is the best way to take the object below and turn it into a parameter string to send via ajax?

I am expecting to return a parameter string like the following ip=111.111.111.111&hostname=rr.com&city=mycity and so forth.

below is my ipinfo object

```
{"ip":"111.111.111.111","hostname":"rr.com","city":"MyCity","region":"Ohio","country":"US","loc":"41.34.23","org":"Inc","postal":"1234","timezone":"America/New_York","readme":"https://www.google.com"}"
```

```
    var myKeys = Object.keys(ipinfo);
        var queryString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < myKeys.length; i++) {
            var theKey = ipinfo[i];
            if (queryString !== "") queryString += "&";
            queryString += theKey + "=" + JSON.Stringify(ipinfo[theKey]);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seens like you need to `JSON.parse()` your object first. Also you can try:

```
Object.entries(JSON.parse(ipinfo)).map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`).join('&')
```

Comment: Be sure to URL encode this before using it as an actual querystring.

Comment: Thx, i forgot :)

Comment: This worked great. This really cleaned up my code a lot too. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well first off, `JSON.stringify("a string")` returns `"\"a string\""`, so you cannot append that in the URL. I recommend letting the native value to string conversion do the job. Instead however, you should properly URL encode each value:

```
queryString += encodeURIComponent(theKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(ipinfo[theKey]+"");
```

Second, you probably have your object in a string form, eg. `"{\"bla\":1234}"` and so `Object.keys` returns `0` for `"{"`, `1` for `"\""` and so on - for each string index, a number. To get it as an object, you have to parse it:

```
 const myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
```

Actual implementation of these two can be seen in @MarcosLuis nice answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this in detail. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JoeZ Happy to help. I also should mention: Do not use `Object.keys` to get array/string indices. It does return them, but it's not correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method to do it, that it accepts a string param of how the queryString was before the changes so it can merge the params object with the existing ones.

In your case, you would do:

```
ipinfo = {"ip":"111.111.111.111","hostname":"rr.com","city":"MyCity"};
attachURLParams ("http://some.site.com", ipinfo);
```

and would get:

> "http://some.site.com?ip=111.111.111.111&hostname=rr.com&city=MyCity"

The method with some doc comments inside:

```
attachURLParams = function (str, paramsObj, overWriteBool=true) {
    /* function adds parameters from json paramsObj to url string
    will work even if param already exists in the string.
    Overwrites existing params by default
    USE: var params = {var1:"value1", var2:"value2"}
    someURL = "http://www.test.com";
    someURL = attachURLParams(someURL, params);
    returns: http://www.test.com?var1=value1&var2=value2*/
    let ind = str.indexOf('?');
    const buildString = (mainPart, paramsObject) => {
        var attached = "?";
        for (var key in paramsObject) {
            attached += key + "=" + paramsObject[key] + "&";
        }
        // remove last "&" and return
        return String(mainPart + attached).slice(0, -1);
    }
    if (ind > -1) {
        var param_array = str.substring(ind + 1).split('&');
        var oldParamsObj = {},
        theLength = param_array.length;
        // keep all existing params in params object
        for (var i = 0; i < theLength; i++) {
            var x = param_array[i].toString().split('=');
            oldParamsObj[x[0]] = x[1];
        }
        // add new params to oldObj
        for (var key in paramsObj) {
            // skip if already there or not
            if (oldParamsObj[key] && !overWriteBool)
                continue;
            oldParamsObj[key] = paramsObj[key];
        }
        // build the string from scratch
        return buildString(str.slice(0, ind), oldParamsObj);
    } else {
        // no params in string, just add all mine
        return buildString(str, paramsObj);
    }
}
```

**Important:**
the method does not have a responsibility to escape or encode the params. You should take care of that in the object values or after you get the params string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data property on the ajax request if using jquery.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/endpoint",
      method: "GET",
      data: { "MyFirstParameter" : someVariable, "MySecondParameter" : someOtherVariable},
      success: function(data){
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
```